# Why was this question on "use of magic comments in go" deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101458/what-are-the-syntactic-and-semantic-rules-for-meaningful-comments-in-go) that was correctly marked off topic because it asked for the location of something (a specification) where none exists.

I don't normally ask such questions because I can find things through my own research (asking on stack overflow is almost the last resort). I hadn't noticed that such questions were off topic.

I reworded it so that it was more like [this on topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go) and requested it was reviewed.

Instead it was deleted automatically.
It is not very old so doesn't meet the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) criteria.
It also says when I tried to edit it "no more edits allowed as its been deleted".

Why was this question deleted instead of being reviewed?

---

Note: this was not the intended question but was how it was understood due to how it was originally written. I was not aware that asking what is wrong with a question is not the same as asking why it was deleted. I was also not aware of the timeline feature or that users <10K cannot view deleted posts. The intended question is now a new question [Why is this question about "magic comments in go" still considered off topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377207/why-is-this-question-about-magic-comments-in-go-still-considered-off-topic)
There is also a subtlety to "reviewed". I think of reviews like "code reviews" and had the expectation that reviewers would leave comments which is not a requirement on SO.

Comment: Looking at "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that" it seems the roomba criteria is 7 days not 30. So that page is out of date?

Comment: When did you edit it?  Within five days of closure?  If so, I suspect there's a reopen review where people decided it should stay closed.

Comment: I edited it multiple times due to further research on the question and also in response to moderation. I tend to edit my posts a lot.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Was that edit within five days of closure?

Comment: I edited it at least 5 times within 5 days of closure probably more. SO doesn't show the full history as far as I can tell.

Comment: You can see the full history here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53101458/timeline

Comment: To ask a meta-meta question why is this question attracting down votes. I couldn't find anything in the meta stackoverflow FAQ saying its off topic to ask questions about your own questions.

Comment: It was submitted for [reopen review](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53101458/timeline) twice, with 3 Leave Closed and 1 Reopen for the first review task; 3 Leave closed and no Reopen for the second.

Comment: Revision history is pretty accurate; it will lump revisions by the same user within five minutes into the same revision, but otherwise, they are pretty decent.  Since you did edit it, I bet it went through the reopen queue, and wasn't good enough to reopen.

Comment: @BruceAdams You should defiantly break that habit of constantly editing your posts over and over again with tiny changes that don't meaningfully improve it.  That's just going to cause people to stop checking back on your question due to being annoyed at seeing so many trivial changes, and they won't notice if you then make some *meaningful* change to the post.

Comment: The timeline link is very useful. Now I know about I've found https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125170/faq-for-how-to-access-questions-timeline as well

Comment: @Servy perhaps not defiantly :). I can see that would be a problem for off topic questions. I edit when I see a mistake. My understanding which seems to be backed up by the review links Andy posted is that its not the same reviewers each time. That's probably a good thing. Lots of small edits wastes more peoples time which is probably a bad thing but again judging by the timeline SO is cleverer than that and waits a bit.

Comment: @fbueckert points out [here][https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377197/are-questions-about-specific-questions-off-topic-on-meta-stackoverlow/377199#377199] that this question attracted down votes because it is based on the false assumption that my question wasn't reviewed rather than that it was reviewed as was rejected. So I now realise this question is actually two different ones. So what I'm going to do is rephrase this one so to reflect thet question I already had in emphasis as I have an answer for the false "It wasn't reviewed" part. Though probably I should just delete it

Comment: @BruceAdams The point is that rather than seeing a mistake, editing, then finding another mistake, and editing, and so on, you should look over the *entire* post, find all of the problems you can, fix all of the problems you can, and *then* save the edit.  As for who sees it, when it comes to review, your post will just stop going to review if you keep editing it like that.  Outside of review, it'll often be a similar group of people following the tag, especially when the edits are around the same time.

Comment: The reason why it was deleted is clear: it was closed and 9 days without edits or reopen votes happened.

Comment: I renamed this to distinguish it from my actual question - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377207/why-is-this-question-about-magic-comments-in-go-still-considered-off-topic. That only 10k people can see the original might explain why people only answered the "why was it deleted rather than reviewed" part of the original question. As its been answered and commented on lots I can't actually delete this question now. It stands monument to my epic fail :)

Comment: Changing your question to completely replace the question with an entirely different question is not OK.

Comment: I didn't I tried to split it into two parts. The title was wrong because "why was this question deleted" is too common. The very first revision has in emphasis the question I was trying to ask. I was not changing the question. I tried to delete it but as that is not possible I accept the answer to the *wrong* question and changed the question to match.
Rolling it back does not help either! Also its very hard to edit faster than the rest of the people on meta!

Comment: Your entire question was about you thinking that it was erroneously deleted and not reviewed. The last sentence was on another topic. The vast majority of the content of the post was not about that other topic, which means that the other topic is tangential to the question asked. The tangential part is the part that should be removed and moved to a new question seeing that the vast majority of the post was addressed here. It's just logical. Otherwise you are invalidating the entire discussion up to this point, and for the sake of what?

Comment: Surely I did remove the tangental part - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377207/why-is-this-question-about-magic-comments-in-go-still-considered-off-topic - which Servy has now answered. What am I missing?

Comment: @TinyGiant think I see the confusion. I did try and remove the wrong bit then changed my mind and split it 2 minutes later (as you can see on the timeline for this question). As Servy pointed out earlier I am editing too many times. I wasn't expecting my meta post to be so much more popular than the post itself.  I also didn't expect others to be editing my questions at the same time as me.

Comment: [Revision 3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/72d46b68-8938-40cb-9fdb-57b6dc2d0f36/view-source): _"Remove false premise, making the actual question asked unambiguous"_ was the edit where everything went off the rails, which is why I rolled it back to the edit before that. It looks like you tried to revert that somewhat then Braiam changed the title again.

Comment: Yes. Rollback is a heavy tool. The default preference should be for the user to be encouraged to edit their post first. Though as servy notes one of my failings is that edit too often (save regularly - you never know when the internet will break)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was reviewed. Twice.

- [Review one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21299688): Result was to leave it closed.
- [Review two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21342070): Result was to leave it closed.

The question was deleted with the reason `RemoveAbandonedClosed` after the second review failed to reopen it.

> **If the question was closed more than `9` days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past `9` days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and show as `RemoveAbandonedClosed`

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/186281)

Comment: That is useful information on two levels. I now know how to see the review as well as the time-line. That says why it was deleted but if I'm being pedantic it does answer my emphasised question as to what is still off topic about the question.

Comment: @Bruce that's an entirely different question. You asked _"Why was this question deleted instead of reviewed?"_ when in-fact it was was reviewed. This explains that it was reviewed _and_ why it was deleted. If you want an explanation as to why your question was reviewed to be left closed 6 times, you should ask another question about that.

Comment: Actually I asked two questions. The one in the title had a false premise (my question was reviewed and found wanting). The one emphasised in the body "what's wrong with it" was the question I wanted to ask. That's not ret-conning but lack of knowledge about how meta works. Its all got a little bit too carry on up the jungle for me now - https://malagabay.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/the-physics-of-the-oozlum-bird/