# Are questions about specific questions off topic on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about a question, and it was rapidly downvoted.
So this new question is:

Are questions about specific questions rather than classes of question, off topic on Meta Stack Overflow?

If I were to guess I would think the downvotes are because a question about a single question is less generally applicable than a question about a class of questions (like this one).

If SO wants to discourage those kinds of questions a good way of doing it would be to mention the timeline and review features in the meta FAQ. It's not there assuming [this is the correct link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: See [Voting is different on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Downvotes are usually (dis)agreement with the premise or the feature request.  Your previous question was based off of an incorrect premise that your question was deleted without being reviewed.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: I know voting is different on meta but it didn't explain the downvotes.
@fbueckert: that does explain things

Comment: Related: *[Meta does in fact have low quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377208)*

Comment: Its hard to distinguish between downvotes that are because the question is bad and downvotes because of disagreement. To consider this question for example. Is it bad because I should have known or done enough research to realise specific questions are on topic or because my guess was wrong? or simply because its yet another new user interpreting downvotes as crticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all. We even have a [tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) for those kind of questions.

Comment: If that is true then why was my meta-question (and this one as well) downvoted?

Comment: Downvoted doesn't mean "off-topic".  Downvoted on Meta usually means "I disagree".  Check the link posted in the comments for more context.

Comment: @Bruce Also, what's happening is that the meta users do know that downvotes don't cost rep on Meta, so they flow out a bit more freely than on the main site.

Comment: @Patrice Downvotes on questions don't cost the voter rep on any site.

Comment: @Makoto Since you were looking for examples of what I was trying to bring up [in this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377208/meta-does-in-fact-have-low-quality-questions) your comment here is a great example of the problem I was trying to address.

Comment: @Servy I meant 'for the downvotee'. Cost in the sense of 'costing someone else something'. Could have made that point clearer.

Comment: @Servy:  This question is in reference to [this question by the OP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377194/1079354) in which they believed a question wasn't reviewed.  I'm not seeing how that question is poor so I don't see how my comment is inappropriate or should be diminished.

Comment: @Makoto - My question was poor because I didn't realise that "what's wrong with this question?" and "why was it deleted?" are two different questions - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377200/what-should-i-consider-before-posting-a-question-about-a-specific-question.

Comment: I now believe it was downvoted based on an assumption I should have looked at the timeline and because <10k users could not answer my intended question.
I agree with @Servy votes do broadly mean the same on meta as normal - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377208/meta-downvotes-dont-just-mean-disagreement-some-questions-are-low-quality?noredirect=1
The problem with the votes was no-one explained that to me even with the "new user" flag. That was discouraging but the final outcome is okay.

Comment: I'm not sure I care to guess about the downvotes on this question. It is either because I voiced my guess rather than just asking the question or because in users here think downvotes are different and voted accordingly.

Comment: @Makoto The question was asking why it was deleted, not why it wasn't reviewed.  The reason it was deleted is shown in the help center.  The answer to the question was simply someone copy-pasting the help center guidelines, which they could have easily read on their own, into an answer.  It's not useful to have question with people just copy-pasting the help center guidelines because people didn't read them.

Comment: @Servy The copy pasting of the guidelines was not why I accepted that answer. My original question title was "why was it deleted (rather than reviewed)", though the body asked "what is wrong with the question?" which is a different question. It was reviewed but I didn't know that. I wrongly assumed my post would trigger an informal review of the post as I desired rather than an explanation of the process which is a FAQ.

Answer (score 7):

No; if it were off-topic, the community would have voted to close your question. But nobody has cast a close vote on it.

Generally, specific-question questions tend to be asked from a point of view that the community disagrees with. Usually because most of these questions tend to be complaints, or their reasoning simply isn't in line with site policies (e.g. asker insists their question isn't opinion-based, but it demonstrably is), or the usual reasons may apply (e.g. false premise, lack of research effort, unclear (which would be a reason to vote to close)). These are possible reasons why they get downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

The downvote tooltip is, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

You posted a question answered by simply reading the help center's criteria for question deletion, which your question met.  You just didn't do your research.

If your question was off topic, rather than just not useful, the votes and comments on it would have indicated that it was off topic.

Comment: My research did not reveal the timeline feature. I expected such a feature existed but I didn't know the name and I wrongly assumed it was a feature for high rep meta users only. You need to know its called 'timeline'. Its not in the FAQ either so far as I can see. Its not https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta or https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @BruceAdams Why would you need to know anything about the timeline?  That has nothing to do with you knowing why your question was deleted.

Comment: Knowing when your question was edited and reviewed makes a big difference. I assumed it was not reviewed because either the review process would have  accepted my new version of the question or someone would have had a helpful suggestion as to why they thought it was still bad. There is no notification of a review occurring directly to a user.

Comment: By comparison almost everytihng I've done on meta has ultimately resulted in useful feedback.

Comment: @BruceAdams And yet whether or not your question was specifically reviewed has nothing to do with whether or not it gets deleted.  You didn't ask, "Was my question reviewed" you asked, "Why was my question deleted", and answer you only needed to read the help center section on deleted questions to figure out.

Comment: That is a very subtle difference. I didn't intend to ask either. I wanted to ask "what is wrong with it" and I did read that page before posting. You can tell by the fact I referred to "roomba" criteria.
I honestly expected people to interpret the quesiton as being what is wrong with the question as I'd emphasised that and why else would I ask?

Comment: @BruceAdams People aren't going to vote on your post based on how you *intended* to ask it, they're going to vote based on how you *actually* asked it, and what you actually asked was why it was deleted.

Comment: My point is, it was a bad question but not because I didn't research it.

Comment: @BruceAdams But had you done your research you'd have found the answer to your question, and others wouldn't have had to quote the help center back to you for you to get your answer.

Comment: I refer you to my [other comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377197/are-questions-about-specific-questions-off-topic-on-meta-stack-overflow#comment652195_377198) on the accepted answer.

Comment: @BruceAdams You saying that you didn't ask the question you intended to ask doesn't change the question that you actually asked.  You *wanted* to trigger a review of your post, but what you *asked* was why it was deleted, which is something you could have trivially found by reading the help center.  Your question is reviewed based on what it *is*, not what you wanted it to be.