# Why is this question about "magic comments in go" still considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, closed-questions, list-questions

**Note: This is a deliberate split from [Why was this question deleted (instead of reviewed)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377194/why-was-this-question-deleted-instead-of-reviewed) not a duplicate of it.**
That question confusingly asked both this question, "why is the post off topic", and "why was it deleted" which are two different questions. The former is answered by looking at the original question. The latter is answered by looking at the timeline and reviews.

---

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101458/what-are-the-syntactic-and-semantic-rules-for-meaningful-comments-in-go) that was correctly marked off topic because it asked for the location of something (a specification) where none exists.
I don't normally ask such questions because I can find things through my own research (asking on stack overflow is almost the last resort). I hadn't noticed that such questions were off topic.
I reworded it so that it was more like [this on topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go) but it still did not pass a reopen review

**What is still wrong with it in its current form?** (as a question not me being needlessly verbose as usual)

[image: deleted question]

[image: comments]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your edits didn't really remove the requests for links to third party products, you just added *additional* questions.  It's still read to me like it's asking for references to the same documents you were asking for before.

Now the question is *even worse*, because not only is it asking multiple different questions, but the additional questions you've added seem to be *very* broad.  It's not my area of expertise, but seeing things like "Are there any other uses I've missed?" about some rather core language concept (given that topics like that can often be discussed at excruciating detail, if you really want to) are big red flags. That's not a specific question at all.

Comment: I find "Are there any other uses I've missed?"  questions are useful but they need community wiki answers otherwise you get one answer per possible use. That only makes sense if the number of possible answers is strictly finite as it should be in this case.

Comment: Your assertion that you think the question can't reasonably be answered in the site's Q/A format is *precisely why such questions aren't appropriate*.  The fact that in your view someone *can't* actually post an answer that answers the question *is exactly the problem with it*.  CW isn't a feature that's there so that questions that are so broad they're unanswerable become acceptable.  Finally, the possible responses to a question like that aren't finite at all.  An unbounded request for information on a topic can go on *forever*.

Comment: If exactly 5 things exit and I list 3 and ask if I missed any the request is strictly bound. A precise answer listing all 5 or just the 2 I missed is sufficient.
This is completely different from asking "are there any tutorials on X" which will change regularly (and is also off-topic as a request for recommendations).

Comment: @BruceAdams But "things that you might have missed about [topic]" just *isn't* a bounded list of 5 things.  It's a core concept that you can explore in basically as much depth as you'd ever want to.  There's *always* something more someone could say about it.  So list questions are bad in general, but this one is *particularly* bad because it's neither a bounded list, nor a short bounded list.

Comment: Why are you assuming topic is a "core concept" that is unbounded? 
I linked to a similarly bounded question in my original one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go. 
If we were talking about "uses of comment" that *is* too broad but my question is about "uses of comments *as directives*". Comments in go aren't just comments. Go uses comments in place of annotations or attributes in C++. There is a finite list of attributes for C++xx and I can look them up in the spec. There is a finite list for go but there is no specification including them all.

Comment: Sorry if this appears argumentative but list-questions are sometimes on topic:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180335/are-there-good-list-questions-as-opposed-to-bad-list-questions
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326951/are-questions-asking-for-feature-sets-of-specific-software-versions-on-topic/326952#326952

Comment: @BruceAdams But your question doesn't meet those criteria for a good list question.  You asked a poorly defined list of things that's not bounded or short, and even said yourself that a single person couldn't answer with a single correct complete answer.

Comment: my suggeston that bounded list questions should often have CW answers assumes that is a way to avoid having multiple competing answers not that it is an absolute requirement

Comment: Ignoring the list question point which we dispute, I think your main point boils down to everything after the horizontal rule beginning with "this comes from considering godoc". I think, If I'd deleted that the question would probably have passed a reopen review.

Comment: @BruceAdams Why ask this question if you're just going to completely ignore all of what you're told and claim that you're right?  If you don't actually want to hear what's wrong with your question and how to fix it, then don't waste people's time by asking.

Comment: I'm not ignoring your points at all. I accepted your answer. I think it is a widely agreed fact that **finite** bounded list questions are on topic. You believe the list is not finite and I believe it is. My question was bad because it didn't focus properly on the finite list.

Comment: @BruceAdams Accepting my answer while saying that you think it's wrong and that the question is good and shouldn't be changed is still ignoring it, for practical purposes. I don't care about what answer is accepted, I care about you actually taking what you've heard to heart and fixing the question.  And no, list questions aren't automatically good because they're finite.  It needs to be a *small*, finite, *unchanging* list.  There are lots of things that are technically finite, and yet still unreasonably broad.